# AspNet Core AttributeRouting does not discover routes if Startup is in different assembly

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, attributerouting

I have a scenario where we have a "standardised startup" for many small AspNet Core websites.

A seemingly obvious solution to achieve this is to refactor the `Startup.cs` class into a separate common assembly (as `Infrastructure.Web.Core.Startup`). We then have each small AspNet Core website reference it the common assembly and use that startup class instead:

```
        public static Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder( string[] args )
        {
            return new WebHostBuilder()
                   .UseKestrel()
                   .ConfigureServices( collection => { } )
                   .UseContentRoot( System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() )
                   .UseStartup<Infrastructure.Web.Core.Startup>(); //.UseStartup<Startup>();
        }
```

Somehow, this breaks attribute routing in the sense that the routes are not hit. No errors, but not routing. **The moment I copy the class back into the website project (with the exact same code) it works again**.

As a test, if I wrap the Startup.cs class in the common library in a local startup class (like below), it also works:

```
    public class Startup
    {
        private readonly Infrastructure.Web.Core.Startup _startup;

        public Startup( IConfiguration configuration )
        {
            _startup = new Infrastructure.Web.Core.Startup( configuration );
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration => _startup.Configuration;

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices( IServiceCollection services )
        {
            _startup.ConfigureServices( services );
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure( IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env )
        {
            _startup.Configure( app, env );
        }
    }
```

If I had to take a guess, it's probably something to do with the Dependency Injection.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

FYI: It's using typical AspNet Core 2.1 projects

**UPDATE**
Incidentally, if I use inheritance it also works but the derived class must be in the same project as the website. I guess it seems obvious, but thought I include that information for completeness sake:

```
    public class Startup : Infrastructure.Web.Core.Startup
    {
        public Startup( IConfiguration configuration ) : base(configuration)
        {
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fix this by adding the following statement to your services in your `Startup.cs` method.

```cs
services.AddApplicationPart(typeof(AnTypeInTheOtherAssembly).Assembly);
```

This will tell the View/Controller Discovery to also check for the new location. Your Project which contains the `Startup.cs` file would be the Startup Project, and all the others would be just references and libraries or similar.

As of .Net Core 3 you can use something called `Razor Class Libraries`, see the [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/ui-class?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio). This will automatically add this your Controllers and Views to the discovery, it also has debugging support and will work just as a normal Class Library would.